# Native mmap error

Tags: java, memory, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I kept getting  the following error in `catalina.out` after around 5 - 6 hours of running my application:

```
There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.

Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 503226 bytes for committing reserved memory.

An error report file with more information is saved as:

/tmp/hs_err_pid1.log
```

I'm using tomcat 8 running in AWS Linux t2.medium instance (General purpose). There's only 1 application running, no other application at all.
What is the issue?

This is the full [pid log file](https://pastebin.com/NncgBaYH)

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when the OS says there is virtual memory available when later this memory cannot be allocated.

I would make sure you have plenty of swap space and your JVM (which is much more than just your heap size) is small enough to comfortably fit inside this instance.

EDIT: I can see

> Memory: 4k page, physical 4047964k(101228k free), swap 0k(0k free)

This means your machine is only 4 GB with no swap, and it was almost out of memory. You either need to make your memory usage smaller (though it's not obvious to me how you would do that) or use more memory, at least until you work out how to shrink your consumption.

Comment: You are actively using most of your memory (3.8 GB), so adding some swap space will help a little, possibly just enough.

Comment: @Kayaman Use a larger instance. 4 GB isn't a lot of memory these days https://www.solid-run.com/product/cubox-i4x4/

Comment: weird, CMIIW, heap size (if not configured) will default to 1GB, correct? according to the log, 3.8GB memory was used, if heap only took 1GB, who took the 2.8GB? which part of JVM took it? or is it another process outside of JVM?

Comment: @musicsquad most likely the JVM is using space to manage connections/threads which are part of the heap but it could other programs as well.